# Trying to understand a change of function in a ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I'm trying to understand the following change. Given this equation:

$2 z'' (1 + z^2) + (z')^3 = 0$

and writing $w = z'$, $z'' = w \dfrac{dw}{dz}$ reduces to:

$$-\dfrac{dw}{w^2} = \dfrac{dz}{2 (1 +z^2)}$$

I don't understand that change of function. Is it $w(t)$ or $w(z)$? If it is $w(t)$ why the second ODE relates $w$ to $z$ instead of $w$ to $t$? If it is $w(z)$ how can it be $w(z) = z'(t)?$

Could you explain the function change in detail?

This is from http://www.liv.ac.uk/~pjgiblin/papers/giblin-warder.pdf page 8 (close to the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to get rid of the $(z')^3$ term.

Straight off, we just let $w = z'$.

Of course this is $w(z)$, so $w' = \dfrac{dw}{dz}$.

When we substitute into the ODE, we have $w = z' \rightarrow z'' = \dfrac{d^2w}{dz^2} = ww'$, so we get:

$$2w w'(1+z^2) + w^3 = 0 \rightarrow -\int \dfrac{dw}{w^2} = \int \dfrac{dz}{2(1+z^2)}$$

When you separate and solve the ODE, you then substitute back.

From the above, you will get $w(z) = ...$, and from the original substitution, we have $w = z'$.

We set $z'(t) =$ above result and solve this new ODE to get a result for $t$.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! Went to the gym and just got back from a 5-mile walk. It was a bone chilling 72 - degrees today and maybe 74 or 76 tomorrow! :-) It is so weird being in shorts on XMAS eve! Hope you are having a great day! :-)

Comment: @amWhy: Wow, you are almost at 3000 answers! I am not even $1000$!

Comment: Can anyone explain why it is $w = w(z)$? For me, if i have $ z = z(t)$ then $z'(t)$ so if $w = z'$ i would think that $w(t) = z'(t)$ and $w'(t) = z''(t)$ and $z = \int w$, why is it $ w = w(z)$??

Comment: @Amzoti: Here, it is about $-3^{\circ}$ Centigrade. +1

Comment: @Trollkemada: Recall, we are making a change of variables in order to solve it in steps. So, we are saying that $z$ is a function of $t$. However, we are using the change of variables as $w(z) = z$. After we solve this intermediate step, then we will solve for $z(t)$.

Comment: @B.S.: That sounds COLD!!! It has been a long time since I have been in temps like that :-)! Hope you are having a great Holiday season my friend!